# Bug in importing project code classes in android studio 3.0

Tags: kotlin, android-studio-3.0

So, say I have this code,

[image]

And then, normally, if I want to import that class, i just hover on the red-coded code (in this case `MenuType`), and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. But, annoyingly, instead of importing the class, it turns into this:

[image]

And it's error.

To make it work, I need to manually insert the supposed-to-be-imported package into the `import` section, and it works normally. It's workable, but kinda annoying.

This however, work normally with non-project code (classes in dependencies, etc)

Anyone knows what caused this and how to fix it? Maybe it's because of Kotlin?

P.S. I think I didn't find this kind of bug in Android Studio prior to 3.0

Comment: Does pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time on the full import prompt to replace it with a short form?

Comment: @madhead doesnt work. It automatically create the long one